Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'
As I'm new to Android studio so its hard for me to remove this error !!
this is the error showing on doing rebuild project :

A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
54 actionable tasks: 54 executed
The build scan was not published due to a configuration problem.
The Gradle Terms of Service have not been agreed to.
For more information, please see https://gradle.com/help/plugin-terms-of-service.
Alternatively, if you are using Gradle Enterprise, specify the server location.
For more information, please see https://gradle.com/help/plugin-enterprise-config.


`My Build.gradle(Module file) :
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        // jcenter() is deprecated; remove if not necessary
        // jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:3.0.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.4'
        def nav_version = "2.5.0"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.5.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.5.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false

}

tasks.register('clean', Delete) {

    //noinspection GrDeprecatedAPIUsage
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`



My Build.gradle(app) :
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // For Kotlin projects
android {
    compileSdk 34
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnitPlatform() // Enable JUnit 5 platform
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.md'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alphaomega"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        languageVersion = "1.9"

    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    namespace 'com.example.alphaomega'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.13.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.recaptcha:recaptcha:18.5.1'
    //loading button
    implementation 'br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:2.2.0' // Removed space//Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0' // Removed space
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2")
    androidTestImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2")


    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.0"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.44"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.44"
    //noinspection LifecycleAnnotationProcessorWithJava8
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.8.4"

    // (Optional) If you also have JUnit 4 tests
    testImplementation("org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.9.2")
    //circular image
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0' // Removed space

    //viewpager2 indication
    implementation 'io.github.vejei.viewpagerindicator:viewpagerindicator:1.0.0-alpha.1' // Removed space

    //stepView
    implementation 'com.shuhart.stepview:stepview:1.5.1' // Removed space

    //Android Ktx
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.7.7'

    //Dagger hilt
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")

    //FireBase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:23.0.0'
}
// Allow references to generated code
kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}`

`
Help me to find what's the error !!!
